# Using visual profiler

Tags: profiling, cuda

I have some code in CUDA that I want to profile.Unfortunately on the machine I work  visual profiler does not work.Would it be possible  that I  am able to test the code  on a visual profiler on  some other machine or something like that?
(basically I am looking for a workaround  so that I can find bottlenecks).

Comment: did you finally find something useful?

Comment: @Werner: nope ...do you have any suggestions

Comment: have a look at  this: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=57443

Answer (score 2):

Use this guide: [Profiling CUDA Applications on Windows with NVIDIA Compute Visual Profiler](http://blog.cuvilib.com/2010/10/28/profiling-cuda-applications-on-windows-with-nvidia-compute-visual-profiler/)

Answer (score 1):

Since an answer hasn't been accepted yet, I suggest giving the newest version of Visual Profiler a try.

The new NVIDIA Visual Profiler (v4.1) supports automated performance analysis to identify performance improvement opportunities in your application. It also links directly to the most useful sections of the Best Practices Guide for the issues it detects. The Visual Profiler is still available for free as part of the CUDA Toolkit on NVIDIA's developer web site: http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda.

If you're still not able to get it working, please file a bug via your (free) NVIDIA registered developer account so the team working on Visual Profiler can investigate further.